# Cable With Same Plug And Slot (RJ11), What's The Purpose?

Tags: cord-and-plug, connectors

I know most connectors that have the same type of plug and slot, or slot and slot, are generally used as extenders. However, I have a cable that's far too short to be useful as an extender. Yet, it's clearly RJ11 (6P2C) for both its plug and slot ends. What's the purpose of this connector, or any similar to it?

I have pics here (the first pic got some reflection and blur, but I can assure you that it's 6P2C):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like a DSL filter. DSL "piggybacks" on a regular voice line. The DSL modem will automatically block out voice frequencies. DSL filters are used on all connections EXCEPT the DSL modem to block DSL frequencies from the voice devices (phone, fax, answering machine).

Comment: That is correct.  DSL filter for Internet over phone line (DSL).